# Unreadable bytecode database tar.gz on windows (Maxmind)

Tags: mysql, bytecode, tar

Following my previous question (Maxmind world cities database issue (MySql)), for which I did not receive any solution, just closed my question with couple comments (anyway, thanks for the comments).

I repost my question in an other way : how could somebody import a database contained in txt file under bytecode form, file compressed in a tar.gz file (may be twice), and this on MySQL for Windows.

Here is the file : http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"under bytecode form*"? Bytecode is usually used by progrmaming languages that use a virtual machine to execute like Java.

Comment: Apologize, what I mean is when I gunzip the file, the content of the txt is as follows : M worldcitiespop.txt ¤ýYs$·’ ¾Ï¯È7Î˜‘e±/”Ô§ÔªSjIÔ9gZOVÁÜŠ™•üµÝf×ìÚ¼Îý¾‘ÕWVJ ÁÏ¬‡ÃýÇÍ°Þo·?öûãíý—/ízÑ?Ú—~³¾ýmóuX6{ˆþÝ [...].

Comment: Apparently it's zipped twice. Just rename the extracted file to .zip and you should be able to extract it again

Comment: ok, i've found a way but your idea definetly helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem which seems to be affecting a number of people, me included. The problem is currently being discusssed at the [MaxMind forums](http://forum.maxmind.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2738). You may find it helpful to look- hopefully it can be resolved soon.

[EDIT] It's been solved! The file WAS compressed twice, as you said. See the link for details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with a_horse help : as he said, the file is twice zipped (tar.gz), but in the wrong way.

So here is the process : gunzip the tar.gz file. You gonna have a worldcitiespop.txt. Rename this file as a tar.gz. Gunzip (force if it's required) this file. You gonna obtain a worldcitiespop.tar file. Rename this file as a txt and here is it!

Answer (score 0):

When you have malformed files of this sort, the first advisable thing is to use a program like [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).  `file` looks at the first few bytes of a file for *[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)* which identify the format of the file, ignoring the potentially-misleading extension.  Using this tool, you could have determined the filetype, changed the extension to the appropriate one, and continued extracting until you had the plaintext you were after.

I hope you'll pardon the broad answer, especially after you've already found a solution to your specific problem, but for the purposes of future visitors to the site, it is more likely they have the general problem of "unable to open a file which has the wrong extension" than your specific issue.

Comment: thank you very much. In fact, i'm working on windws, so file does not exist, but thanks again...

Comment: @Laslo: File does exist on Windows. I specifically noted that was your environment, and linked to the Windows version.  Check the link.

Comment: You have totally right! so, let me thank you again, this tool will be usefull in the futur.